# Formatted logging

Tags: c#, log4net

I can do formatted print to console:

```
Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}", 1,2);
```

How to make the same with `log4net`?

```
log.info()
```

Comment: It's a simple question but no need for all the downvotes, it's actually quite hard to find this infomation on Google, if you wanted to use log4nets own formatter and not `String.Format()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
log.InfoFormat("{0} {1}", 1, 2);
```